# Decimal to days hours

Tags: arithmetic

I have $10.73$ and $37.27$ days and I need to convert both to the **days:hours** format but I'm getting confused mid way.

Taking $10.73$ as example I can do $10.73\times24$ to get $257.52$ hours but how do I go about presenting it that 10.73 days is equal to x days and y hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your time of $10.73$ is decimals of days, in which case you already know that there are $10$ days.  To get the number of hours, you multiply $0.73 \times 24=17.52$ so there are $17$ full hours.  To keep going you multiply $0.52 \times 60=31.2$ to get the minutes and $0.2 \times 60=12$ to get the seconds.  The final answer is $10:17:31:12$

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the $10$ for the number of days. This leaves you with $0.73$ days that you need to present as hours.
$$0.73\cdot24=17.52$$

As days:hours, it's $10:17.52$

Alternatively you could take the number of hours ($257.52$). Divide by $24$ and round down to get the days, and mod by $24$ for hours.

$$\lfloor\frac{257.52}{24}\rfloor=10$$
$$257.52 \bmod 24 \equiv 17.52$$